# Geodesic Distance function in R for sets of users

Tags: r, function, social-networking, distance, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the geodesic distance between users of a social network. Supposing I have 2 users U1 and U2 how do I go about declaring the function in R such that the geodesic distance function returns the distance between any two users from a large data set consisting of 1000's of users.

```
d <- function (U1(lat1,lon1),U2(lat2,lon2))
{
  rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- lon1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- lon2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- R * c
  miles <- d*0.621
  return(c(d,miles))
}
```

The above code does not work . I am not sure how to declare two users with (lat,lon) coordiantes within a function definition in R. Is there any other way of doing it so that say if I have data set with 1000 users I might be able to calculate the geodesic distance between any 2 users.

Answer (score 0):

This library looks promising:

```
library(geosphere)
distm(c(lon1,lat1), c(lon2,lat2))
```

with two matrices:

```
distm(
  matrix( c(
    1, 3, 
    2, 2,
    3, 1
  ), nrow = 3, ncol = 2),

  matrix( c(
    4, 6, 
    5, 5,
    6, 4,
    3, 1
  ), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
)
```

matrix of n users and distances between them:
    # number of users
    n <- 100

```
# positions
lat <- rnorm(n, 46, 1) 
lon <- rnorm(n, 14, 1) 

#distm also accepts a matrix (2 x n):
cmat <- matrix( c(lat, lon), nrow = n, ncol = 2)
distm(cmat)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer . It works good but can I do it without rnorm and is there any specific reason the mean value of r norm is 46 for lat and 14 for long.

Comment: I used rnorm just as a (random) data generator. In your case lat an lon vectors will be produced from some database

Comment: I have already read my lon1,lat1 from one dataset similarly lon2,lat2 from another dataset into the distm function above . So what lat lon will I be reading into positions . I am a little confused since there is just one lat lon in #positions and cmat matrix

Comment: You can call distm with two matrices. Or with two points like: `distm(c(lon1,lat1), c(lon2,lat2))`

Comment: Yeah I have called it and executed line 2  successfully but I am doubtful about the cmat c(lat, lon) part since I have two lon, lat how do I execute c(lat, lon) or should it be cmat <- matrix(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2),....)

Comment: Depends on what you want. The matrix form gives you the matrix of all distances between all combination of points. If you are interested in the single distance then use the 2 vectors form. The variant with two matrices would be useful when you need the distances between any of points of different group.

Comment: Could you just help me with the variant with two matrices because I have been trying for some time but I am unable to figure out how to how to calculate the distance between any points of two different groups

Comment: I recently had a situation where I had to calculate the haversine distance for millions of lat/lon pairs in a dataframe (not matrix format). To solve this problem I wrote an Rcpp package which is both dataframe compatible and fast. You can install it from CRAN `install.packages("hans")`. The source code is here https://github.com/alexhallam/hans